# How to prevent markdown folding of # comments in fenced code?

Tags: folding, filetype-markdown

I have python examples in a markdown file in a code fence (e.g. when I convert a jupyter notebook into a markdown document). These snippets sometimes have code comments in them starting with #. The markdown folder, however, recognizes these as headings, so folds them as chapters. This, in turn, messes up the document outline.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

It would be really hard to do reliably.

Basically, if you brave enough, check what current markdown plugin uses for folding and try to rewrite it:

1. `:set foldmethod?` to find out if it is `expr` or not
2. `:set foldexpr?` to find out what is the function name `expr` uses
3. create your own `MarkdownFold()` function (or whatever name is 2. showed)

So you would end up copy pasting existing `MarkdownFold` function to your vimrc and start hacking.

```
function! MarkdownFold()
  let line = getline(v:lnum)

  ...
  ...

  return "="
endfunction
```

In the end you will have to analyze if current line is python comment and skip it. Which would be the trickiest part. Is your line in a code block? How far backwards you should scan for code block beginning? Etc.

And depending on your implementation your vim would probably become slow for markdown files.

PS, I have tried to do similar thing for my implementation of folding for asciidoctor files, but couldn't do anything good, so I decided not to bother with it. Anyway `==` is far less common than `##` :)

**UPDATE**

So it just came to my mind that it is possible to get syntax group of a current line. And you should be able to check if it is a markdown header or not. I have implemented it for my asciidoctor plugin and did this also for a markdown (I already have it in my `after/ftplugin` folder to tune it for markdown frontmatter).

Here is the result:

```
function! MarkdownFold()
  let line = getline(v:lnum)

  " Regular headers
  let depth = match(line, '\(^#\+\)\@<=\( .*$\)\@=')
  if depth > 0
    " check syntax, it should be markdownH1-6
    let syncode = synstack(v:lnum, 1)
    if len(syncode) > 0 && synIDattr(syncode[0], 'name') =~ 'markdownH[1-6]'
        return ">" . depth
    endif
  endif

  " Setext style headings
  let prevline = getline(v:lnum - 1)
  let nextline = getline(v:lnum + 1)
  if (line =~ '^.\+$') && (nextline =~ '^=\+$') && (prevline =~ '^\s*$')
    return ">1"
  endif

  if (line =~ '^.\+$') && (nextline =~ '^-\+$') && (prevline =~ '^\s*$')
    return ">2"
  endif

  " frontmatter
  if (v:lnum == 1) && (line =~ '^----*$')
      return ">1"
  endif

  return "="
endfunction
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `masukomi/vim-markdown-folding` plugin seems to solve this issue of # comment in fenced code being treated as headings. The difference with the default markdown folding that comes with the installation is that with the plugin, all headings are explicit and you cannot fold to a certain level, which may actually be what one wants unless you have too many headings.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! If you have info on how the plugin solves the issue, that would make a great addition (via an [edit]).

Comment: So the above-mentioned solution is for Vim 8.1, which has a ``markdown.vim`` filetype plugin dated 2016 Aug. 29. Install the ``vim-markdown-folding`` using a plug-in manager like ``vim-plug`` and the # comment in a code block will be displayed properly. In Vim 8.2 the default markdown.vim filetype plugin is dated 2019 Dec. 05 and has the comment inside the fenced code block issue solved. No need to have the plug-in.